# Particle Swarm Optimisation Explained

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, genetic-algorithms

Is anyone able to provide an intuitive explanation of how particle swarm optimisation works? For example how to minimise a function f(x,y,z). Also, does particle swarm optimisation work for multi-objective optimisation problems, and if so, how?